# Lumen: PhpStorm says there's an error in a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstorm, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.1 and latest version of PHPStorm, I have a problem in many to many relation, not sure if it's a coding mistake or if I should report a bug to PHPStorm.

Task model

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Auth\User', 'task_user');
    }

    public function domain()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Domain', 'domain_id');
    }
```

User model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_user');
}
```

UserTask model

```
class UserTask
{
}
```

Sometimes everything works great, like in the add

```
$task = new Task();
$task->domain_id = $domainId;
$task->title = $title;
$task->due_date = $dueDate;
$task->submit_date = Carbon::now();
$task->created_by = $userId;
$task->save();
$task->user()->sync($assignee);
```

But in the edit for example

```
$task = Task::find($taskId);
            $task->title = $task->title === $title ? $task->title : $title;
            $task->due_date = $task->due_date === $dueDate ? $task->due_date : $dueDate;
            if ($task->is_done != $isDone) {
                $task->is_done = $isDone;

                if ($isDone == 0) {
                    $task->closed_by = null;
                    $task->closed_date = null;
                } else {
                    $task->closed_by = $userId;
                    $task->closed_date = Carbon::now();
                }
            }
            $task->save();
            $task->user()->sync($assignee);
            return $this->response->statusOk();
```

This line

```
$task->user()->sync($assignee);
```

PhpStorm says

```
Method 'user' not found in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Referenced method is not found in subject class.
```

It's essentially the same code that is working in the add, should I report a bug to PhpStorm or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are they DocBlock comments in your Task Model for the relationships? If they indicate anything other than the appropriate relationship, then PHPStorm won't display correctly.

In your case, the DocBlock would read - 

@return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany

Comment: @DarrenCraig why would it read the add action then? I mean it gets the edit and delete wrong but the add right